# ASP.NET 4.0 IIS Registration

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-applications, iis-6

I have a web server running IIS 6 which has .NET 2,3.5, and 4 installed.  Everytime I install a .NET 4.0 web appication the ASP IIS Registration tool is ran which is clearing out some important registry entries for EnableExtionlessUrls.  We have reinstall the .NET 4.0 framework but are still having the same problem.  Has anyone else experienced this issue?
Thanks,

Comment: This isn't programming related and looks like a question better suited for [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: It has to do with installing a web application, so I would consider it programming related.

Answer (score 0):

Are you publishing the website from Visual Studio? And is it an MVC website? .NET 4.0 MVCs have issues with IIS 6.0

Comment: No. It is being installed from a web setup project that was created in VS 2010 and it is not an MVC website.  Thanks though.